# Load i18n for all components Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-i18n

When using vue-i18n, I need to add this to every single component:

```js
setup() {
  const { t, locale } = useI18n();
  return { t, locale };
}
```

Is there any way to preload the `t` function to all my components?

Answer (score 0):

You can load and switch languages as below.

in i18n.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
Vue.use(VueI18n)

function loadLocaleMessages () {
  const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i)
  const messages = {}
  locales.keys().forEach(key => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1]
      messages[locale] = locales(key)
    }
  })
  return messages
}

const locale  = localStorage.getItem('language') || 'tr'
export default new VueI18n({
  locale:  locale,
  fallbackLocale: locale,
  messages: loadLocaleMessages()
})
```

in main.js

```
import i18n from './i18n'

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App),

})
```

Answer (score 0):

[`createI18n()`](https://vue-i18n-next.intlify.dev/api/general.html#createi18n) creates a Vue plugin that makes `vue-i18n` available globally for all components:

```js
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

const i18n = createI18n(/*...*/)
createApp(App).use(i18n).mount('#app')
```

`t` is then available in the template as [`$t`](https://vue-i18n-next.intlify.dev/ja/api/injection.html#t-key), and `locale` is `$i18n.locale`.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-i18n-init?file=src/main.js)